# Python response with excel file

Tags: python, http, aiohttp

I'm using **api_hour** for API web server and trying to response to request with excel file. But it is much more difficult than I thought.

If I use **nodejs** or **django**, it is fine and there are many guide for it. But **api_hour** is not. The following code is mine.

```
headers = {
                'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="excel_file.xlsx"',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'status,Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Cookie, Accept, X-PINGOTHER',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*',
                'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes'
            }
            self.responseHeaders = multidict.MultiDict(headers, )

return Response(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                status=self.status,
                headers=self.responseHeaders,
                body=response['excel'])
```

What I found is that the other frameworks, for example **nodejs**, **django**, and **ASP.NET Core**, respond with file using **there own encapsulated functions** so do not assign binary data, which is `response['excel']` in this code, directly to body.

Is there any way to respond with file ? especially excel ? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [looks like](https://github.com/Eyepea/API-Hour/blob/61854c7a216d1cad4a2325ba99e8995416ed8135/examples/all_in_one.py) `Response` is [`aiohttp.web.Response`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#response).

You may thus want to look into the [`StreamResponse`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#streamresponse) class instead, which you can stream data into, if that's what you're asking.

Or, if you need to (try to) force the client to download your data as a file, add a `Content-Disposition` header:

```
Response(
    ...,
    headers={"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=my-excel.xlsx"},
)
```

Comment: Yes, it is aiohttp.web. And I missed write I already write header before example code. Sorry about that. And I tried with your answer. But it doesn't work...